# How do I manually `npm audit fix` a single security issue?

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-audit

I have a number of issues reported by `npm audit`, and by running `npm audit fix` it does fix several of them. However, doing so also breaks my build for some reason. I think I know which fix causes the issue, but I'd still like to fix the *other* issues.

Is there a way to have npm do whatever it does when I run `npm audit fix`, but only for a single issue/dependency?

---

I know I run `npm i`, but that also adds the updated dependency to `package.json` (even with `--package-lock-only` flag), which I don't want. I just want npm to update the `package-lock.json`, like it does when I run `npm audit fix`, but just for a select subset of issues.

Answer (score 37):

You should be able to use [`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-update) to achieve what you want here. What to do is slightly different depending on whether you are using `npm` 7.x or `npm` 6.x. I'm using 7.x, so that's what I show below.

Let's say `npm audit` produces output like this:

```
# npm audit report

minimist  <0.2.1 || >=1.0.0 <1.2.3
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1179
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/extract-zip/node_modules/minimist
  mkdirp  0.4.1 - 0.5.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of minimist
  node_modules/extract-zip/node_modules/mkdirp
    extract-zip  <=1.6.7
    Depends on vulnerable versions of mkdirp
    node_modules/extract-zip

3 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

This is indicating that we need to update `minimist`, `mkdirp`, and `extract-zip`.

Let's do `npm ls` to get an idea of what versions and dependencies we're dealing with.

```
$ npm ls minimist mkdirp extract-zip  
scrape-text@1.0.0 /Users/trott/ucsf-ckm/scrape-text
├─┬ puppeteer@2.1.1
│ └─┬ extract-zip@1.6.7
│   └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│     └── minimist@0.0.8
└─┬ semistandard@14.2.0
  ├─┬ eslint@6.4.0
  │ ├─┬ file-entry-cache@5.0.1
  │ │ └─┬ flat-cache@2.0.1
  │ │   └─┬ write@1.0.3
  │ │     └── mkdirp@0.5.3 deduped
  │ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.3
  │   └── minimist@1.2.5 deduped
  └─┬ standard-engine@12.0.0
    └── minimist@1.2.5

$
```

Because the colorizing is kind of important, here's a screenshot of that last one:

[image: Screenshot of the previous text output to show colorization highlighting of the modules we care about]

Let's see what happens if we run `npm update minimist` to just update that package. Let's use `npm ls minimist` to see if anything changed. (You can also see if your `package-lock.json` file changed and do a diff.)

```
$ npm ls minimist
scrape-text@1.0.0 /Users/trott/ucsf-ckm/scrape-text
├─┬ puppeteer@2.1.1
│ └─┬ extract-zip@1.6.7
│   └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│     └── minimist@0.0.8
└─┬ semistandard@14.2.0
  ├─┬ eslint@6.4.0
  │ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.3
  │   └── minimist@1.2.5 deduped
  └─┬ standard-engine@12.0.0
    └── minimist@1.2.5

$
```

Nope, no change. We still have the same versions we had before. OK, let's try the next one, which would be `mkdirp`.

```
$ npm update mkdirp

changed 1 package, and audited 244 packages in 1s

3 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
$
```

That `changed 1 package` seems promising. Let's see what that did:

```
$ npm ls mkdirp    
scrape-text@1.0.0 /Users/trott/ucsf-ckm/scrape-text
├─┬ puppeteer@2.1.1
│ └─┬ extract-zip@1.6.7
│   └── mkdirp@0.5.1
└─┬ semistandard@14.2.0
  └─┬ eslint@6.4.0
    ├─┬ file-entry-cache@5.0.1
    │ └─┬ flat-cache@2.0.1
    │   └─┬ write@1.0.3
    │     └── mkdirp@0.5.5 deduped
    └── mkdirp@0.5.5
```

That updated `mkdirp` to 0.5.5. You can test that out and see if things still work.

If you now do `npm update extract-zip`, that will result in a clean `npm audit` run.

Hopefully, this gives you an idea of how to update the packages one at a time without modifying `package.json` in the process. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this well-written and insightful post.
It would be even greater if you could also include the full `package.json`.
I believe that's all it takes to make it a
["minimal, complete, and verifiable example" (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: not sure how this fixed the `minimist` issue?

Comment: @alfredopacino In this case, `mkdirp` and `extract-zip` both have `minimist` as a dependency. Trying to update `minimist` without updating those two won't work because the old versions of `mkdirp` and `extract-zip` limit what new versions of `minimist` can be installed. By updating those other packges, `minimist` ends up getting updated as well.